# What logic should go in the domain class and what should go in a service in Grails?

Tags: oop, grails

I am working on my first Grails application, which involves porting over an old struts web appliction. There is a lot of existing functionality, and as I move things over I'm having a really hard time deciding what should go in a service and what should be included directly on the model?

Coming from a background of mostly Ruby on Rails development I feel strongly inclined to put almost everything in the domain class that it's related to. But, with an application as large as the one I'm porting, some classes will end up being thousands upon thousands of lines long.

How do you decide what should go in the domain versus what should go in a service? Are there any established best practices? I've done some looking around, but most people just seem to acknowledge the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, the main guideline I follow is:

> If a chunk of logic relates to more than one domain class, put it in a service, otherwise it goes in the domain class.

Without more details about what sort of logic you are dealing with, it's hard to go much deeper than that, but here's a few more general thoughts:

1. For things that relate to view presentation, those go in tag libs (or perhaps services)
2. For things that deal with figuring out what to send to a view and what view to send it to, that goes in the controllers (or perhaps services)
3. For things that talk to external entities (ie. the file system, queues, etc.), those go in services

In general, I tend to err on the side of having too many services than having things too lumped together. In the end, it's all about what makes the most sense to *you* and how you think about the code and how you want to maintain it.

The one thing I would look out for, however, is that there's probably a high level of code duplication in what you are porting over. With Grails being built on Groovy and having access to more powerful programming methods like Closures, it's likely that you can clean up and simplify *much* of your code.

Comment: One good way to spot methods that should be on the domain is if you have a method that is passed a domain class as its only argument then that method probably belongs on the domain.  I would also expand on @cdeszaq's answer and also say that if you're dealing with more than one `instance` of a domain class, put it in a service.  For example if you're mutating several instance of a specific class I'd put that in a service.  In general though, use your best judgement, talk to your team about methods you're unsure of where they belong.

Comment: Just adding to that is that service methods are by default transactional: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/services.html#transactionsRollbackAndTheSession

Answer (score 1):

I personally think it is not only a decision between service and domain class but also plugins or injected code.

Think of the dynamic finders like `Book.findAllByName()`. It's great that Grails injects them into the domain classes. Otherwise they would have to be copied to each domain class or they would be callable through a service (`dynamicFinderService.findAllByName('Book')` -argh).

So in my projects, I have quite a few things which I will move to a plugin and inject into the domain classes...

Comment: Very good point. Especially for new Grails "converts", plugins can seem to be a bit of a magical black-box, but they are very powerful and can dramatically simplify code.

Answer (score -1):

From a Java EE point of view: No logic at all within domain classes. Keep your domain classes as easy and short as possible. Your domain model is the core of your application and must be easy to get.

- Grails is developed for dependency injection. All logic which resides in domain class is hard to test, and to too easy to refactor.
- You cannot exchange implementations like with services (DI).
- You cannot test the code of your domain class easily.
- You cannot scale up your system, since your implementations cannot be pooled like services.

My recommendation: Keep every logic in services. Services are easy to test, easy to reuse, easy to maintain, easy to re-configure.

Specific to grails: if you change your domain class, the in-memory-DB will be killed, so you lose your test data, which prevents you from rapid prototyping.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer a little bit and explain what you mean by 'easy to get' and why you believe there shouldn't be any logic in a domain class?

Comment: Grails doesn't really follow the JEE model very strictly. Validation and DB mapping are bundled into the domain objects, so you are already getting more than a basic bean. I would strongly vote _against_ anemic domain classes, as you seem to suggest here, since it requires more classes and complexity for very little gain.

Comment: You make a few good points with the update, but you are still ignoring the fact that validation and DB mapping are already tied into the domain classes. You still seem to be advocating for anemic domain classes, which I am very much against. That said, any logic above and beyond dealing with only a single instance of a domain class should definitely go into a service, in part for some of the points you mentioned.

Comment: In general i put all constraints which will directly influence the db mapping into the domain class. All other kind of validation and constraints go into command objects in order to be more flexible later on. Well i like anemic domain classes, since testing is everything. However this might be influenced from personal experience.

Comment: @crudolf - Since you can have a command object copy the domain object validation, your argument for keeping validation out of the domain objects in that regard is invalidated, and I'm not sure how reducing _any_ object to essentially just a data structure increases test-ability because testing exercises _logic_ and an anemic domain objects _doesn't have_ logic.

Comment: 1) Declarative constraints are no logic. 2) Testability: Check my response.

Comment: In Grails a domain class is just as easy to test as a controller or a service.

Comment: I am not talking about technology, but maintainability and extensibility.